# Receiving post data with different encodings

Tags: c#, post, encoding, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

I am trying to integrate with a third-party system and in the documentation is mentions that when they send xml data via HttpPost, they sometimes use "**text/xml charset=\"UTF-8**"" for the "Content-Type", and in other cases they use "**application/x-www.form-urlencoded**" as the Content-Type.

Would there be any differences in parsing the request? Right now I just pull the post data using the folllowing code:

```
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);

        String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the stream reader, you should pass the encoding specified on the HttpRequest object.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream, request.ContentEncoding);
string xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

This should allow you to get the original contents of the request into a proper .NET string regardless of whatever encoding is used.

Answer (score 1):

Always give preference to use Encoding.UTF8. This will ensure that, in most cases, the reading is always done in a correct coding standard.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an encoding to your StreamReader at construction like so:

```
  StreamReader s = new StreamReader(new FileStream(FILE), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

`application/x-www.form-urlencoded` is [HTTP Form Data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), **not** XML.

Your code would most likely fail if you expect that `Request.InputStream` will be a parsable XML string when the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www.form-urlencoded`